Is the weight of a floating body zero?
My physics book says that the apparent weight of a floating body is zero which is understandable since the buoyant force cancels out the gravitational force on the body.
However, further in the book it also explicitly states that the weight of a floating body is zero. I do not get that part. Since weight's formula is $W=mg$, the fact whether it is floating or not should not matter. The gravity is still 9.8 m/s² and the mass of the body hasn't changed.
So, how should I think of it?
PS: For reference, the book I have mentioned in Selina Concise Physics for class 8. Check out the exercises behind the physical measurements chapter

Ask yourself: If you step onto a balance is your weight zero? Although the floor generates a force, which is exactly $m\cdot g$, you probably are not weightless. ;)

@Semoi, Exactly! but then is the course book wrong? Also, doesn't the normal force(to which I am new) act when the body is floating?

Honestly, you know the answer of your question. My advice: Don't try to read each sentence separately, but try to understand what the author tries to emphasise. In your case the author probably tries to put the emphasis onto the "counter force". From time to time I also include statements in scripts just to emphasise a point, although deep down I know the statement is wrong/incomplete.

Please specify the title and author of the text. Where in the text are  these terms defined?

You are right. The weight of an object has got nothing to do with whether it is being cancelled out or not at any given moment. You have a weight while floating in water, which is cancelled out by buoyancy, just as you have a weight while lying on solid ground, which is balanced out by a normal force.
Apparent weight is a term used for what is "left" of the weight value after some has been subtracted away, e.g., by buoyancy.
Weight is just another name for gravitational force when the other mass is very large. We do not call the gravitational force by Earth on Mars a weight, since its mass is not negligible compared to Earth's, but we do call the gravitational force by Earth on a stone a weight. Essentially, when it is reasonable to replace the gravitational force formula with $m$ times $g$,
$$F_g=G\frac{mM}{r^2}\approx mg,$$
then we call it weight and use a symbol like $w$ instead.

But, then is the course book wrong?

The course book is not wrong, since the apparent weight is 0, so if you put the mass on a spring it will not be elongated. But you could say the book is not precise enough not telling what it calls weight

Textbooks may contain mistakes. It is enough that the word "apparent" was erroneously dropped in the second statement. I wouldn't be surprised.

@SanchitBatra Course books are rarely wrong if written and published by proper authors. But it happens that they can be oversimplifying, as others suggest. Do you have the full quote? Then we can have a quick look.

"weight of a floating body is zero"
It depends on how it is floating. Floating in space, yes the weight is zero. Floating in water, no.
In fact, weight is really only a sensible concept in the context of a body near the surface of a planet.  Otherwise it's best to speak of gravitational force
$$F = G\frac {mM}{r^2}.$$
Because the mass of Earth $M$, radius of Earth $r$ and Newton's constant $G$ are (basically) the same everywhere on Earth, we condense these into a single constant $g=GM/r$ and arrive at the common formula
$$F=mg$$
where $F$ is known as the weight.

That definition of weight is not what a scale measures. The OP asks about what some call apparent weight. You have defined what some call "true weight".

Seems to me he is asking about both
